# Setting tab width based on file type

Tags: vim

I'm trying to learn to use Vim. I like indenting by 4 spaces but use 2 spaces for certain languages, such as Nim and MoonScript. I tried adding this to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.nim :setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
```

Problem? It doesn't do anything! All that happens is that the tab does nothing when I press it! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing it in a ftplugin?

Comment: @lcd047 What do you mean?

Comment: Something like this: `echo setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 >>~/.vim/ftplugin/nim.vim`

Comment: Check `:help filetype-plugin`. If your tab does nothing it is probable that you had something mapped to it - you could try `:imap <tab>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.nim setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
```

This should work (after restarting Vim / re-editing an existing file via `:e!`) fine, but it mixes *filetype detection* with *filetype settings*. Vim has an intermediate abstraction called *filetype*, which you should use. With it, you map file globs like `*.nim` to a filetype `nim`, and then define settings either via an `:autocmd FileType`, or a *filetype plugin* in `~/.vim/ftplugin/nim.vim` (for the latter, you need `:filetype plugin on` in your `~/.vimrc`).

#### Steps

So, create a filetype detection in `~/.vim/ftdetect/nim.vim`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.nim setfiletype nim
```

Then, create a filetype plugin in `~/.vim/ftplugin/nim.vim`:

```
setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
```

You can check that these are loaded correctly via the `:scriptnames` output. After a restart of Vim, this should work, and you can add additional settings to the latter file. If your filetype is derived from another, you can also add `:runtime! ftplugin/javascript.vim` (for example) in there to get those settings, too.